# How can I create a rake task that will always run when any Rake task is ran?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

From what I remember, in the documentation is specified that in the test environment, the database is always cleared even when you run rake ( with no arguments ). I'd like to achieve such a thing, so that it doesn't matter if I run a task or not, when I run rake, there's always a Rake task being executed. Is this possible? Is this where the default task kicks in?

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called `rakefile` in the directory you want to run the task from.
This code will make it so that if you just type "rake" my_default_task will run:

```
  task :default => 'my_default_task'

  task :my_default_task do
     puts "Now I am doing the task that Tempus wants done when he/she types 'rake' in the console."
  end

  task :my_not_default_task do
    puts "This isn't the default task."
  end
```

However, if you typed `rake my_not_default_task`, then `my_default_task` would NOT run.  If you want it to run regardless here is one thing you can do:

```
task :default => 'my_default_task'

task :my_default_task do
    puts "This is the default task"
end

task :my_not_default_task do
  puts "This isn't the default task."
end

Rake::Task['my_default_task'].invoke
```

The last line in this code ensures that my_default_task runs even when you call some other task, so if you typed `rake my_not_default_task` the `my_default_task`'would also run.

EDIT:
When you're working with rails you can put the tasks above in a file in the `lib/tasks` folder with an extension of `.rake` and rails will automagically run them when you do `rake`

[Jason Seifer has a real nice tutorial on rake](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial).

Comment: Sure, but how do I make so that even if I invoke a Rails related task, my task gets ran?

Comment: @Tempus I edited the answer to answer your question about rake in Rails.